# Working With Files out of solution file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file

I have 2 ASP.Net MVC projects, one of them is admin which includes a folder named "Images" to hold images that are uploaded.

The second project is only to retrieve data from database and images located in the first project files.

My problem is that in the second project, I can not access the images which are located in the first project files.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you need to access the files, it's just the file path to where the images are that you need?

Comment: no,it's not.  my exact problem is that i want to write for example "C:\Users/Desktop\Images\sky.png" in src of image tag.

Comment: Ok, so what I think you need to do is create a virtual directory for the location of those images in your IIS instance. The path to the images would then be accessible through your local web app. i.e. http://localhost/myvirtualdirectory/images/sky.png

Comment: yes, that's correct.  thanks!